Identical(?) Tailwind vs Inline vs Stylesheet styles - Tailwind incorrect on initial render
I've got three grids, each with sliders as children.

1 is styled with tailwind, here
1 with inline styles, here
and 1 with a stylesheet here

If you look at the styles below, is there any reason for them to be rendering differently?
The Tailwind version renders incorrectly initially. You have to resize the window for it to display as the others do. I understand that sliders (in this case keen-slider) can be particular with their styling, but to my naive eye the styling looks exactly the same:
Tailwind:
<div className="slider-grid grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 p-4 w-[75%]">
  <div className="flex flex-col overflow-hidden max-w-[100%] gap-y-[10px]">
  </div>
</div>

Inline:
<div
  className="slider-grid"
  style={{
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr",
    width: "75%",
    gap: "1rem",
    padding: "1rem",
  }}

    <div
      className="slider"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        overflow: "hidden",
        maxWidth: "100%",
        rowGap: "10px",
      }}
    >
  </div>
</div>

Stylesheet:
.slider-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 75%;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

Tailwind on render:

Tailwind after resize (exactly like both inline and stylesheet versions on initial render):


I don't see anything actually different, maybe this is a tailwind config issue?

I think it's an issue with keen-slider, although I'm not sure why. In your other examples, it adds min-width and max-width to the elements, but not in the Tailwind example. Maybe it's not detecting the Tailwind stylesheet?

@KarsonJo do you mean on the slides themselves? I'm personally seeing min/max width inline (both the same values), but that could be my devtools being weird?

@justnut I'm not sure, but it affects both codesandbox and my local dev environment

Yes, but in the Tailwind version it doesn't have those two values at first, it does after a resize.

@KarsonJo definitely there for me prior to resize, in both chrome and FF. weird!

on the slide only the values change on resize, not what properties are applied - i've got min-width, max-width, transform (translate3d(0px 0px 0px))

it might be due to the minor delay in loading tailwind CDN, have you tried to install tailwind locally ?
